# How to remove ordered list using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have given **2 codes** below--  
**Code 1 :**
Below is my code which is using `querySelector` to select the class name which I want to remove.

But it only removes the first list element and doesn't work for remaining list which has also class name same as the first list element.
Why does this not work after removing first list element (after remove first list, class name 'remove' is also still there and is not working for them) ?

Now go to **code 2** to is my solution for the question .

```js
//JAVASCRIPT ----CODE 1-----
let ol = document.querySelector('.remove');

ol.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    let length = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;
    if(length > 1){//ignore to remove all list
    let remove = e.target.parentNode;
    remove.parentNode.removeChild(remove);
    }
});
```

```css
/* CSS*/
ol li {
    background-color: rgb(104, 144, 113);
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 250px
}
       li span.remove {
           float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: silver;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 23px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div><p>click on minus icon to remove list item</p>
    <ol>
        <li>list1 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
        <li>list2 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
        <li>list3 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
        <li>list4 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
        <li>list5 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**Code 2 :** solution of code 1 .
I use here `querySelector` for **ol** which is ordered list and inside of the querySelector I use `if(e.target.className == "remove")` to remove list item .

```js
//JAVASCRIPT ----CODE 2-----
let ol = document.querySelector('ol');

ol.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target.className == "remove"){ // only select element which has class name 'remove'
    let length = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;
    if(length > 1){ //ignore to remove all list
    let remove = e.target.parentNode;
    remove.parentNode.removeChild(remove);
    }
    }
});
```

```css
/* CSS same as in code 1*/
ol li {
    background-color: rgb(104, 144, 113);
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 250px
}
       li span.remove {
           float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: silver;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 23px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML  same as in code 1-->
<div><p>click on minus icon to remove list item</p>
    <ol>
        <li>list1 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
        <li>list2 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
        <li>list3 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
        <li>list4 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
        <li>list5 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**Help me:**
but i  don't want to use : `document.querySelector('ol')` which select the whole ordered list, due to which it will **waste memory** .
I want to achieve my answer which select only class name 'remove' instead of whole ordered list.

> We can use `let ol = document.querySelectorAll('span.remove')` which
>   select all elements of class name 'remove' which store as an array in
>   variable ol but after it how can we select that array element which
>   will be remove **?**

Comment: *Have you determined yet whether wasting memory is going to have any negative impact on your application?*  If you have not done so, then your question is effectively moot.

Comment: @RobertHarvey *I have not determined yet, but why we store useless data in memory ?   An ordered list may contain 'millions' of recursive list, so to store millions of list in a variable is not good for time complexity in which only some element is needed. Thats why i asked question.*

Comment: @Abhishekkamal attaching the event handler to the `<ol>` is a single function, as there is only one `<ol>`. If you attached an event handler to every `<li>` then you'd can end up with many copies in memory as there are `<li>` elements, this means the `<ol>` method may actually be more memory efficient. Did you test your assumed memory differences?

Answer (score 0):

your code is not working because in your code ol is a collection of all the elements with  class name of "remove". So, you cannot use it like a single element, you should use a for loop on ol to access every single element with class name "remove".

Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ol.length; i++) {
  ol[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to why is not the first version of code running correctly is because you define `let ol = document.querySelector('.remove');` which takes only first element with that class and puts it into memory on the loading page. So then when you put event listener to it, you assign it only to that element, which is missing after you remove one. That's why it works only on the first element. You would have to use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all elements with that class, not only first.

```js
//JAVASCRIPT ----CODE 1-----
let ol = document.querySelectorAll('.remove');

ol.forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    let length = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;
    if(length > 1){//ignore to remove all list
    let remove = e.target.parentNode;
    remove.parentNode.removeChild(remove);
    }
})
});
```

```css
/* CSS*/
ol li {
    background-color: rgb(104, 144, 113);
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 250px
}
       li span.remove {
           float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: silver;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 23px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div><p>click on minus icon to remove list item</p>
    <ol>
        <li>list1 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
        <li>list2 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
        <li>list3 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
        <li>list4 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
        <li>list5 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code does not work correctly.. the 5th element seems to still be there when clicking to remove it??

Comment: Yes, its true but if I remember correctly that was an author's of this question intention. He made himself the condition to remove until 1 item lefts. He never mentioned removing all elements. Just asked why his code does not work after 1st element

Comment: yes, i saw that in the code, but also the comment says `ignore to remove all list`

Comment: I think it is neither me nor you to decide what exactly he wanted to achieve since there were no details about it. I appreciate your effort to make it clear tho.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to remove all that extra code

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.remove').forEach((item) => {
 item.onclick = (event) => {
  let length = item.parentElement.parentElement.children.length;
  if (length > 1) {
   item.parentElement.outerHTML = ""
  }
  
 };
});
```

```css
/* CSS*/
ol li {
    background-color: rgb(104, 144, 113);
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 250px
}
       li span.remove {
           float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: silver;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 23px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div>
  <p>click on minus icon to remove list item</p>
  <ol>
  
    <li>list1 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
    <li>list2 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
    <li>list3 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
    <li>list4 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
    <li>list5 <span class="remove"> - </span></li>
  </ol>
  </div>
</html>
```

Explanation:

Note: 
whenever you see something like `(item) => { etc.. }`  you can think of it as saying   `function (item) { etc.. }`

the two are exactly the same thing.

Now..

`querySelectorAll` selects all elements.

To loop over them you do `.forEach()`

Inside the forEach must be a function  with at least item as the parameter which represents the item being looped over

so `document.querySelectorAll("ol")`  returns  a list of all OL tags

then adding `document.querySelectorAll("ol").forEach((item)=>{ /* item is now each OL element */  })`

then you can do  `document.querySelectorAll(".remove").forEach((item)=>{})` which will get any elements matching the class 'remove'

finally you simply use the .onclick binding to add an event which operates solely on that specific item by doing  `item.onclick = (event)=>{item.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(item.parentElement); }` or it can be `item.parentElement.outerHTML = ""`  which are both the same functionality.